# Concatenate rows (sql server 2000)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, concatenation

I have the following problem when using SQL Server 2000

The following table has around 200 rows.

```
Company / Employee
1005 / A
1005 / B
1005 / C
1010 / X
1010 / Y
1020 / L
1020 / M
etc etc
```

I wish to create the following (comma separated) output:

```
Company / Employees
1005 / A, B, C
1010 / X, Y
1020 / L, M
etc etc
```

I'm having a really hard time with this in SQL Server 2000, while 2005 seems to offer easier solutions to solve this issue! I hope someone has a bright idea to explain how to solve this...

Comment: I didn't even think it was possible in 2005. How did you do it?

Comment: @David: look at `FOR XML` clause.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen solutions using UDFs in SQL 2000, but they are scary - they're basically doing a brand-new `SELECT` for every group that might be executed hundreds or thousands of times.  You're actually better off using a cursor:

```
DECLARE @Temp TABLE
(
    Company int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Employees varchar(4000) NOT NULL
)

DECLARE
    @LastCompany int,
    @Company int,
    @Employee varchar(100),
    @Employees varchar(4000)

DECLARE crEmployee CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT Company, Employee
    FROM @Tbl
    ORDER BY Company
OPEN crEmployee
FETCH NEXT FROM crEmployee INTO @Company, @Employee
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    IF (@LastCompany IS NULL)
        SET @Employees = @Employee
    ELSE IF (@Company = @LastCompany)
        SET @Employees = @Employees + ',' + @Employee
    ELSE BEGIN
        INSERT @Temp (Company, Employees)
        VALUES (@LastCompany, @Employees)

        SET @Employees = @Employee
    END
    SET @LastCompany = @Company
    FETCH NEXT FROM crEmployee INTO @Company, @Employee
END
CLOSE crEmployee
DEALLOCATE crEmployee

IF (@Employees IS NOT NULL)
    INSERT @Temp (Company, Employees)
    VALUES (@LastCompany, @Employees)

SELECT * FROM @Temp
```

There's a solution using a temporary table and `UPDATE` similar to that used to compute running totals, but it's a beast to look at and in most cases won't do much better than the cursor for performance.

If anyone really desperately wants to see the `UPDATE` version, I'll post it, but I suggest trying the cursor version first and seeing if it's "good enough."